# when using django rest frameworks viewset views and model serializers do you need to write tests?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-viewsets

When using django rest framworks viewsets and model serializers do you need to write tests?

Custom implemented code that uses djangos or django rest frameworks base classes such as API view or serializer, I can see needing to write tests for, but when you use the model serializer or the viewset which are tightly connected to each other and require minimal code from us do we write tests?

I want to keep to test driven development, but I have no idea how I would write tests for these cases.

Example here is code from URL to View To serializer To model how would one test?

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'city-list', CityListViewSet, base_name='city-list')
router.register(r'venue-filter-options-list/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)',VenueFilterOptionsViewSet, base_name='venue-filter-options'),
router.register(r'neighborhood-list/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)', NeighborhoodListViewSet,
 base_name='neighborhood-list',


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```
"""
grabs all filter params for the browse venues page
"""
class VenueFilterOptionsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):


    def list(self, request, city):
        self.city = city
        values = Values(
            city = City.objects.all(),
            neighborhood = Neighborhood.objects.filter(city= self.city),
            cuisine=Cuisine.objects.all(),
            privacy= Privacy.objects.all(),
            venueType=VenueType.objects.all(),
            amenities=Amenities.objects.all()
        )
        serializer = VenueFilterOptionsSerializer(values)
        return response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class NeighborhoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Neighborhood
        fields = 'neighborhood'

class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = '__all__'


class CuisineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cuisine

class PrivacySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Privacy

class VenueTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VenueType

class AmenitiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Amenities
# end child serializers for VenueFilterOptionsSerializer


class VenueFilterOptionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    city = CitySerializer(many=True)
    ''' reduntant use of city as cost is low, and needed in case of non site api call, or if user navigates
    to browse venues page before heading to landing page'''

    neighborhood = NeighborhoodSerializer(many=True)
    cuisine = CuisineSerializer(many=True)
    privacy = PrivacySerializer(many=True)
    venueType = VenueTypeSerializer(many=True)
    amenities = AmenitiesSerializer(many=True)
```

models.py

```
# models
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=imgUnique('venueMedia/venueImages'))
    streetAddress= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city=models.ForeignKey(City)
    neighborhood=models.ForeignKey(Neighborhood)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    cuisine = models.ManyToManyField(Cuisine)
    venueType = models.ManyToManyField(VenueType)
    Amenities= models.ManyToManyField(Amenities)
```

Comment: At first: you never need to write tests, but you should. Unluckily you did not provide any sample code to test and any goals of your testing so it hard to explain how to do it.

Comment: coming right up